# I need to print this in printf

Tags: java

I did the program but I need to print this with `printf()`. I need to have 2 digits after the decimal like this 6.00 and it should round it off too. I used `println()` just to try it.

```
    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
        double[ ] x = {1.0, 0.90, 0.80, 0.70, 0.60, 0.50, 0.40, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10, 0.00, -0.10, -0.20, -0.30, -0.40, -0.50, -0.60, -0.70, -0.80, -0.90, -1.00};
        double r = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
                System.out.println(x[i]);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<21;i++) {     
              double y = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2)- Math.pow(x[i], 2));
              System.out.println("");
              System.out.println(y);
        }
    }
```

Here is how it should be lined up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7atLn.png

Comment: If you don't know how to codify the formatting, why do you post the math and for-loops?

Comment: i posted the code up there pls tell me how to format it right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
System.out.printf("%.2f%n", x[i]);
```

---

**EDIT** Here's another idea, based on your desired output:

```
double[] x = { 1.0, 0.90, 0.80, 0.70, 0.60, 0.50, 0.40, 0.30, 0.20,
           0.10, 0.00, -0.10, -0.20, -0.30, -0.40, -0.50, -0.60, -0.70,
           -0.80, -0.90, -1.00 };

double r = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    double y = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r, 2) - Math.pow(x[i], 2));
    System.out.printf("%10.2f%10.2f%n", x[i], y);
}
```

```
      1.00      0.00
      0.90      0.44
      0.80      0.60
      0.70      0.71
      0.60      0.80
      0.50      0.87
      0.40      0.92
      0.30      0.95
      0.20      0.98
      0.10      0.99
      0.00      1.00
     -0.10      0.99
     -0.20      0.98
```

Comment: The first column is correct but the second column is going sideways

Comment: @SaadAbdullah So you want to print `x` and `y` side by side?

Comment: yes ju like the pic shows

Comment: Try `%10.2f` - see [the very extensive JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for all other things you can do with printf.

Comment: "%10.2f" is not right either

Comment: and also like the picture what if i wanted to creat 2 more columns on the side?

Comment: @SaadAbdullah You would have to add to the `for`-loop and change the print statement slightly. e.g. `System.out.printf("%10.2f%10.2f%10.2f%10.2f%n", x[i], y, x2[i], y2)`.